# How to remove the Windows 11 snipping tool from F9 key?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-11, snipping-tool

I want to remove the default snipping tool (which is on F9) and replace it with an other one (and set up on F9 aswell).

**My config**:

- Computer: HP Elite Mini 600 G9
- Monitor: PHL 346E2C
- Keyboard: HP 655 wireless mouse bundle
- Keyboard settings: English (Switzerland) [Image of the keyboard](https://hp3d.herokuapp.com/assets/images/thumbs/products/displays-accessories/commercial-accessories/hp650655wirelesskeyboardandmousecombo.png)

**What I've tried**:
I uninstalled the program called `Snipping tool`, under `Accessibility>Keyboard` I toggled OFF `Use the Print screen button to open screen snipping` and I restarted the computer.

However when I click on F9 I get the default snipping tool (it's on top of the screen and you can chose between 4 modes). How can I remove this snipping tool ?

Comment: (1) It is always easier to set Hot Keys in the third party App than in Windows.  (2) Snipping Tool is not on F9 on my Windows 11 Pro machines (two) or my Windows 11 Pro Insider machine.

Comment: So is it linked to the keyboard ? I mean it's a brand new working station

Comment: I have not seen F9 open the snipping tool.  Always a Win Key on my machines.

Comment: It's related to the keyboard I guess as you can see on this image [link](https://hp3d.herokuapp.com/assets/images/thumbs/products/displays-accessories/commercial-accessories/hp650655wirelesskeyboardandmousecombo.png)

Comment: I guess you are using a very different keyboard. I don't know about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh!

I removed my old comment since it's irrelevant;

I saw you guys found out it's the keyboard's shortcuts.

You should be able change the preferences by pressing FN+SHIFT to "unlock" function.

Explaination:
Shift is also "Function Lock". After pressing FN+SHIFT - then F9 will do it's thing, while FN+F9 will call the snipping tool.

G'luck!

Comment: Works like a charm !